# how to Build V2ray in android studio

Tags: android, github, simulator

I want to run v2ray which is in Github(https://github.com/2dust/v2rayNG) in Android Studio and then run it on the simulator, but there are a series of files that do not exist in the program. Please help me to find the solution.

app\src\main\kotlin\com\vpn\service\V2RayServiceManager.kt:26:8: error: unresolved reference: go
import go.Seq
^
app\src\main\kotlin\com\vpn\service\V2RayServiceManager.kt:30:8: error: unresolved reference: libv2ray
import libv2ray.Libv2ray

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the same problem with the latest version. You can try these options:

- Use [this release](https://github.com/2dust/v2rayNG/releases/tag/1.7.33)
- Download [this file](https://github.com/2dust/v2rayNG/blob/09d854dc784365e5499e444aff065055adcc5105/V2rayNG/app/libs/libv2ray.aar) and copy it to the libs directory.
- Build the libv2ray.aar yourself, as mentioned in the project's README.

Comment: Thank you! I was literally stuck with this issue for 4 hours until I found your answer.